# Error: The input authorization token can't serve the request. with local emulator and Microsoft Bot Framework V4 Bot

Tags: botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use my local CosmosDB emulator as the storage engine for my Microsoft Bot Framework V4 bot and following is the CosmosDBStorage generation code,

```
var cosmosDbStorage = new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
            {
                AuthKey = “default master auth key”,
                CollectionId = “bot-state”,
                CosmosDBEndpoint = “https://localhost:8081”,
                DatabaseId = “production-bot”,
            });
```

We are getting the following error and following is the stack trace of the exception,

```
 at ConnectMe.BotV4.Middlewares.LastActivityMiddleware.<OnTurnAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\vebhupat\source\repos\EUS-Sup-OSEE-CMe-ConnectMeCore\ConnectMe\ConnectMe.BotV4\Middlewares\LastActivityMiddleware.cs:line 49
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.<OnTurnAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.<ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.<RunPipelineAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```

The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get

sun, 22 dec 2019 03:27:48 gmt
'
ActivityId: ec67fec0-0927-4391-b331-00d75973477a, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Windows/10.0.18363 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.9.2

My emulator is working fine at the address, https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html

And I am using a sample application from https://localhost:8081/_explorer/quickstart/DocumentDB-Quickstart-DotNet.zip and I am able to run the flows of doing CRUD operations on the ToDoList sample application,

```
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
```

As per some of the GitHub posts, this can happen due to SSL certificate validation with emulator’s localhost endpoint, which can be disabled with ConnectionPolicy, but there is no such attribute in ConnectionPolicy class.

Can anyone help us troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: That's not an error that I'm familiar with. Can you provide a sample of the document that you're trying to store as well as the code you're using to store it? You'll also want to make sure your v4 packages are updated and/or try [`CosmosDbPartitionedStorage`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/CosmosDbPartitionedStorage.cs). Maybe you need to [export the SSL certs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates)?

Comment: Are you still experiencing an error?